# Why puppet is not able to download latest from snapshot repo

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, puppet, mcollective

We are using **Puppet** and **mCollective** for our server deployments. For both of our **dev** and **test** environments, we release the artifacts (from two different branches) to the same nexus snapshot repo (we use maven `classifier` to distinguish between dev and test artifacts). The artifact details look like:

**Dev Artifact**

```
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<classifier>dev</classifier>
```

**Test Artifact**

```
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<classifier>test</classifier>
```

These artifacts are released through two Jenkins jobs. For Puppet/mCollective we use `LATEST` as the version; however, for some reason it ignores the classifier while determining the latest. What I meant was, lets assume in nexus snapshot repo dev artifact was created at `21-July-2015 1PM GMT` and test artifact was created at `21-July-2015 2PM GMT`. On server, if we want to do a dev deploy, mCollective agent downloads the test artifact from nexus repo (even after we provide the classifier as `dev` in puppet configuration).

I see a script `download-artifact-from-nexus.sh` which I believe is used to download the artifact from nexus repo. This script uses Nexus REST APIs to download the artifact. I am not aware of these REST APIs, but I feel this script does not use `maven-metadata.xml` which clearly mentions which artifact is latest based on classifier. I am new to puppet/mCollective and not sure how to resolve this. Appreciate if somebody can provide some help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with puppet and everything to do with your shell script.

Comment: The script `download-artifact-from-nexus.sh` is not mine; it is provided by Puppet Labs.

Comment: Is it [this file](https://github.com/cescoffier/puppet-nexus/blob/master/files/download-artifact-from-nexus.sh)? You are using that module then (although it does not seem to be available from the Forge). The script was not provided by Puppet Labs, it's from a third party contributor. You might wish to raise the issue with them.

Comment: @FelixFrank, yes, perhaps I saw this file from GitHub and misunderstood. Thanks for clarifying. Could you please let me know without this script, how Puppet would have downloaded latest artifacts from nexus? And, yes, I should raise a bug against the script provider.

Comment: @Niranjan well, Puppet has no native support for `nexus`, so you will have to rely on a module. There are [some alternatives](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rank&q=nexus) available from the Forge. I suggest you try some of them, your mileage may vary.